# Run callback when association is removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I have the following standard association.

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :degree

 after_save :do_something

  def do_something
   puts "done something"
  end
end

class Degree < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :courses 
end
```

I add/remove courses with `@degree.courses = collection` where `collection` is an array of `Course`s.

When `collection` includes a new `Course` everything works as I expect:

- The course is created.
- `do_something` runs.

However, when `collection` doesn't include a `Course` previously associated with `@degree` `do_soemthing` isn't executed while the record is updated (setting `degree_id` to `nil`).

Below an example of a query from my log

> UPDATE "courses" SET "degree_id" = $1 WHERE "courses"."id" IN (SELECT
>   "courses"."id" FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."degree_id" = $2 AND
>   "courses"."id" = $3)  [["degree_id", nil], ["degree_id", 1], ["id",
>   1"]]

Why isn't `do_soemthing` executed? 
Is that the expected behavior? If so, is there another callback I can use to make sure `do_soemthing` is executed when the record is updated with the removal of `degree_id`?

Comment: What's the operation you're doing that should be firing `do_something`?

Comment: I was expecting, as it runs the callback when a new record is added, it runs it also when reming the association. Howver, after a closer look, it goes directly to teh DB, skipping the callback.

Comment: It depends how you're removing that object from the association. If something like `collection.delete(object)` will execute the callback, with something accessing directly the object like `object.delete` it won't.